# In effect, suppress wrapping pseudo-elements

Tags: css, xml

My source is [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) (not HTML) and I can’t modify it.

This would be easy if CSS had a parent selector.

---

This XML

```
<p>Have you heard <quote>I never saw a purple cow</quote>? It is a silly poem.</p>

<p>
It goes like this. <quote><l>I never saw a purple cow.</l>
<l>I never hope to see one.</l>
<l>But I can tell you anyhow,</l>
<l>I’d rather see than be one.</l></quote> Isn’t that silly?
</p>
```

and this CSS

```
quote::before {content:"“"}
quote::after {content:"”"}

/* For lines inside quotes */

quote > l {display:block; margin-left:2em}
```

produce this output

[image]

Is there some trickery to produce the same result but without the two quotation marks I’ve circled?

(It would also be OK if the quotation marks were not eliminated but moved, the opening one to the beginning of the first line and the closing one to the end of the last line of the poem.)

https://jsfiddle.net/mccaskey/ujvny0o1/21/

Comment: I suppose it's not a fixed html structure? if yes you can target only the first `p` to add quotation

Comment: That’s right. The structure isn’t fixed.